# Getting previous route info before rendering in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.js. I have to show a pop up (seperate component) when a user comes from a specific path.
I used a show variable which is by default set to true. As user lands on this page, user will see a pop up. But I want to get the path name in my component so that I will show the pop up only when a user comes from the specific URL.
I used the `beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next)` method for getting the previous path. And according to that I am changing the show variable value.

```
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      if (from.path === '/my-specific-path') {
        vm.show = true;
      }else{
        vm.show = false;
    });
  },
```

But it is showing my pop up because mounting is done before calling `beforeRouteEnter` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    if (from.path === '/my-specific-path') {
      vm.show = true;
    } else {
      vm.show = false;
    }

    next()
  });
},
```

You are missing the `next()`

Comment: I am updating the `show varibale` in next function.

Comment: You have to proceed after you finished modifying the `show` variable.

Comment: I don't know why my code is now running wihout adding next()

Comment: Oh okay. That’s interesting

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the brackets

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    if (from.path === '/my-specific-path') {
      vm.show = true;
    }else{
      vm.show = false;
    }  //this bracket missing
  });
},
```